# Discover Meteor - mrt add bootstrap - Install Error

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I just started the Discover Meteor Tutorial, and when I attempt to:

```
mrt add bootstrap
```

I get the following error:

```
usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/lib/project.js:225
      throw("Package named " + pkgName + " doesn't exist in your meteor in
                                       ^
Package named bootstrap doesn't exist in your meteor installation, smart.json, or on    
atmosphere
```

Any thoughts?  Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### update 3/2/14:

It looks like the book now supports the [official bootstrap package](https://atmospherejs.com/twbs/bootstrap) which you can get via:

```
$ meteor add twbs:bootstrap
```

#### old answer:

It looks like they have not updated the book for the new packaging system. You have some [choices](https://atmospherejs.com/?q=bootstrap) when it comes to which bootstrap version to use. I'm not sure which one the book expects, but you could try the default that comes with meteor:

```
$ meteor add bootstrap
```

Note we are replacing `mrt` with meteor.

If you want bootstrap 3, then you could try:

```
$ meteor add mizzao:bootstrap-3
```

Comment: This does not work for me. it says `mizzao:bootstrap-3: no such package` any idea why?

Comment: @phadaphunk Are you using an old (< 0.9) version of meteor?

Comment: @DavidWeldo I am newbie to meteor. Which one, could you suggest me mrt or meteor?

Comment: @BlueBells Always use `meteor`. `mrt` was deprecated a while ago. Note that I also updated the answer with the official bootstrap package.

Answer (score 2):

```
mrt add bootstrap-3
```

is worked for me. Hope this help!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but luckily, found a solution quite easily. It appears that the Meteorite package manager operates on packages that have already been added to your local project with `meteor add <packageName>` and allows you to manage them more conveniently with the `smart.json` and `smart.lock` files. Consequently, the steps you should take are the following:

1. Install bootstrap with `meteor add bootstrap` in your project (this operation does not write to `smart.json`);
2. Issue the command `mrt add bootstrap` (this command will record your bootstrap package in `smart.json` and `smart.lock` for easier package management with Meteorite).