# Installing bootstrap 3 with meteor

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor, webstorm

I've read a lot of posts about how bootstrap can be included in your meteor project and more recently, I've seen people using

```
meteor add mizzao:bootstrap-3
```

like in [this anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25880243/1063093).

The thing is when I try to do it I get the following error :

```
mizzao:bootstrap-3: no such package
```

Is there another version I need to use or is there another way to add bootstrap 3 to a meteor project.

Comment: I just tried adding the packages in my app. Its working perfectly fine.
you can search meteor packages using `meteor search packagename` to check its availability.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does, but it doesn't on my side. Maybe I have something in my project it doesnt like

Comment: Which meteor version you're using?if it is not the latest one you must use `mrt add bootstrap-3`

Comment: @Rajanand02 Just realised that I'm not on 0.9 since its not available on windows... also your command did not give me an error but it didn't seem to have intalled bootstrap 3 either.

Comment: you must install [meteorite](https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite) to use `mrt` command. I would highly recommend you to use mac or GNU/Linux for meteor development to make use of latest meteor and smart packages.

Comment: yes I'm setting up a linux environment as we speak. I don't want the OS to be a bottleneck through the development. Thanks !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For meteor 0.9 or above

`meteor add mizzao:bootstrap-3`

For meteor < 0.9 use [meteorite](https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite) to add packages.

```
npm install -g meteorite
mrt add bootstrap-3
```

To search for available meteor packages use

`meteor search package-name`

NOTE: search command will work only for Meteor 0.9 or above

Answer (score 2):

You can install the lastest version, simply use this in the project folder:

```
meteor add twbs:bootstrap
```

if you don't find it, it worth trying to update your repository:

```
meteor search .
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows, it wont work.

Comment: Windows is not well supported right now. Better use a Linux VM. and for Bootstrap 3 I prefer the ian package

Answer (score 0):

Installation With Meteor 0.9 and above, install using:

```
meteor add mizzao:bootstrap-3
```

Answer (score 0):

There is now an official package here:
https://atmospherejs.com/twbs/bootstrap

Comment: This isnt bootstrap 3. Is it?

Comment: @shaunakde From what I can see from this file, it should be: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/package.js

Answer (score 0):

I actually set up `mizzao:bootstrap-3` a long time ago, but this was for a much older version of Meteor.

Starting from Meteor 1.3 which offers first-class **npm** support, the recommended approach is to install Bootstrap directly from npm, which doesn't depend on any poorly-maintained (ahem) shim packages:

```
$ meteor npm install --save bootstrap
```

(This also saves `bootstrap` in your `package.json` file so others can install it with `meteor npm install`.)

Then, in any client-side JS file (e.g. `/client/main.js`):

```
import 'bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css';
```

If you're interested in more customized Bootstrap installs using SASS/SCSS, etc. check out **[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37333520/586086)**.