# Meteor kadira no such package

Tags: javascript, meteor

we are developing our meteor application in a windows environment using the unsupported windows version of meteor. The latest release is 0.8.3. Ok in the windows environment we used meteor add for the packages. But if i write

```
meteor add meteorhacks:kadira
meteor add kadira
```

I always get the no such package message. mrt command doesnt work. Any ideas?Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this question is duplicated. Please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26825287/2751392)

`meteor add meteorhacks:kadira` is available only in Meteor 0.9 and above.

For Meteor below 0.9 you have to use Meteorite which is currently not supported by windows.

Comment: a ok i see. is there a way to install kadira manually somehow in windows? I remember i read an article about installing manually packages but the kadira dependencies are many. Must i put all the packages?Is there anywhere a detailed guide or automated process on how to do that?

Comment: I never tried installing packages manually. Even if you do use while updating your application it will cause a lot of issues. I would highly recommend to use GNU/Linux or mac for meteor development. The official windows support is under development. Check the [roadmap](https://trello.com/c/ZMvnfMfI/11-official-windows-support).

Answer (score 1):

I'm developing an application in Meteor 0.8.3 and I have to use mrt: https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite

The command is:`mrt add kadira`

I highly recommend you to upgrade as soon as possible. If you application depends on atmosphere packages, you'll have a hard time try to upgrade it later. Today most packages are obsolete because the creators don't care about it anymore.

Having in consideration that you're using an unsupported windows version: I don't really know if this is going to work. It's work great for Meteor at version 0.8.3 today.